MySQL Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'date' for function str_to_date
I'm attempting to change the date format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD.
Code:
SELECT `date`,
STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM example_table;

Results(success):
date      ---> STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')
7/25/2022 ---> 2022-07-25

Code:
UPDATE example_table
SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y');

Results(error):

MySQL Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'date' for function str_to_date

What am I missing here?

Looks to me like you've got a literal string 'date' in your table

Besides the obvious problem of trying to update your date column, which is text, with a date value, it appears that some of your text dates do not fit the format %m/%d/%Y.  To find those values, you may use the following query:
SELECT date
FROM example_table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') IS NULL;

